# CNAME on a custom domain is changing the url on the address bar with a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cname

I am building a web app and i will like to access the application from another domain using a CNAME record.

The app is running on my main domain (my-domain.com) and i have a second domain (another-domain.com)

I have set up the CNAME for another-domain.com to point to my-domain.com but whenever i visit another-domain.com i get a 301 redirect to my-domain.com

Is there something i need to do that i haven't done yet?
This is my first time working with CNAME so suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: This is a laravel Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNAME is a DNS alias for an A record (IP Address). 
DNS doesn't know anything about 301 Status (which is part of the HTTP protocol).

So the 301 response you're getting is coming from your website (or possibly your firewall/router/load balancer). Check your server logs to see which application is returning the 301 (apache, IIS, NGinX, HA-Proxy, etc), then check the configuration to ensure it's performing the way you want.

For example, in Apache you might have created a new VirtualHost for another-domain.com with

```
  Redirect permanent my-domain.com
```

If you want the same web content displayed no matter what the domain, consider changing the my-domain.com VirtualHost configuration, adding :

```
  ServerAlias another-domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The redirect was coming from the nginx server. There is a configuration file that looks like a middleware for incoming requests. I just had to comment it out in the config.

Comment: where is the configuration?